# What would I do to match a value of just '/' in the "Mounted on" column?

Tags: awk

Assume the following output:

```
➜  ~  df -kl                             
Filesystem                        1024-blocks      Used Available Capacity  iused     ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1                          487401624 207950512 279195112    43% 52051626  69798778   43%   /
/dev/disk2s2                        732238672 242656088 489582584    34% 60664020 122395646   33%   /Volumes/Backup Drive
```

I would like to extract '43%' (column %iused) from the output above. What would I do to match '/'? I get the feeling I need to escape it. In the past I matched a specific string (i.e. CPU usage) without any issue. I would use something like:

```
top -l 1 | awk '/CPU usage:/ {print $3}'
```

But the '/' is giving me trouble. Any ideas?

Comment: You're right again. I've updated the title to be more specific about what I'm trying to accomplish. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments it sounds like this might be what you want:

```
df -kl | awk '$NF=="/"{ print $8 }'
```

If not, do edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Nicely done; just to add an explanation: this matches only mount point `/` (mount points are reported in the last whitespace-separated column, whose values `awk` sees as `$NF`), and reports the 8th field (`$8`), the value in the `%iused` column.

Answer (score 2):

Should be simple!  Try this:

```
df -kl | awk '/^\// { print $5 }'
```

We tell it to find lines where the line starts with a slash.  We specify the slash by escaping it.

Comment: Awesome David! When I run the command "df -kl | awk '/^\// { print $5 }'", it prints two lines (43% and 34%). I need to do an match the line with only one '/' (it currently matches '/' and '/Volumes/Backup'. I tried anchoring the match between ^ and $, but no output seems to be shown. Any ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: Then just switch it to `/^\/[^a-zA-Z]/`  That should match the forward slash at the front of the line when things that are not characters appear immediately after it.

Comment: Wait.. I take that back.  If you know it's /dev/disk1 then match `/\/dev\/disk1`.  I was trying to be generic in what I gave you and what I just posted is looking for the mount point, not the device.

Comment: You're right Ed, done. @DavidHoelzer, I'm not sure if it's safe to assume '/dev/disk1'. I'd prefer to match against '/', just in case.

Comment: Ed, I updated the command with `df -kl | awk '/^\/[[:alpha:]]/ { print $8 }'` and it still prints `43%` and `33%`.

Comment: Nicely done; you could rely on mount point `/  ` always getting reported _as the first one_, so `df -kl | awk '/^\// { print $5; exit }'` should do the trick.